# NodeJS Strict Mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, strict

Are there any advantages to using `"use strict"` in NodeJS? For example, a global object is not a good idea to use, as all your requests will mutate said object (assuming the object in question should be unique to each user, of course). In this case, using strict mode would have been a good idea, no?

I feel like strict mode is a good idea to pair with Node, but I haven't been able to find any pros or cons to it via google.

Disclaimer: I know what `use strict` does, this question is focusing on the server sided pros/cons!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, clarity and speed.

Unlike what the popular answers and question in SO say - the real primary goal of strict mode and the `"use strict"` directive is to eliminate [dynamic scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping) in JavaScript which is why changing arguments via `arguments` and changing `arguments` itself is not allowed, why `with` is not allowed, and so on.

#### Clarity

Strict mode does not allow dynamic scoping, so you can always statically know what a variable refers to. `with` statements, changing variables via arguments and other types of non-static scoping make code less readable, in non strict mode:

```
// example from referenced thread
// global code
this.foo = 1;

(function () {
  eval('var foo = 2');

  with ({ foo: 3 }) {
    foo // => 3
    delete foo;
    foo // => 2
    delete foo;
    foo // => 1
    delete foo;
    foo // ReferenceError
  }
}());
```

This sort of headache is avoided in strict mode.

#### Speed

Strict mode is much faster than non strict mode.  A *lot* of optimizations can only be made in strict mode since it can assume a lot more about what doesn't change and how to resolve references. V8 internally uses this extensively.

References:

- Still not sure what dynamic/lexical scope is? [Read this article by @EricLippert](http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/20/what-is-lexical-scoping/)
- [This Excellent write up by @Domenic](http://domenic.me/2013/03/19/strict-mode-static-scoping/) and the [discussion it references](http://www.mail-archive.com/es-discuss@mozilla.org/msg18408.html).

Comment: `with` and `eval` in the same example? Im shocked the internet didn't explode!

Comment: Because of the additional clarity, testing becomes easier. Little mistakes, such as in variable assignment, can be picked up more readily (e.g. with JSHint) because of the stricter requirements.

Comment: I really liked this answer, its clear & concise. You took the time to write a really good answer, thank you for that.